# Customer Free Form Telephone Number validation error

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Usin API V3 for QBD, getting error:

```
Invalid field value PrimaryPhone: Invalid telephone number: [(555) 555-6286 x112]</Message>
```

The [spec](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/95_legacy/qbd_v3/qbd_v3_reference/020_key_concepts/0700_other_topics#TelephoneNumber) for this states it is a free form number with a max length of 21. So why is this not valid?

Using the API Explorer directly gives this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be considered as a bug.

Using devkit/apiexplorere, I tried the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Customer xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
    <DisplayName>TEL_CUST_DK</DisplayName>
    <PrimaryPhone>
        <FreeFormNumber>[(555) 555-6286 x112]</FreeFormNumber>
    </PrimaryPhone>
</Customer>
```

I got the similar exception.

```
<IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2014-03-20T04:09:34.675Z">
    <Fault type="Validation">
        <Error code="-4000">
            <Message>Operation failed with errors: 
Invalid field value PrimaryPhone: Invalid telephone number: [[(555) 555-6286 x112]]</Message>
        </Error>
    </Fault>
</IntuitResponse>
```

But when I created a new customer in QB and retrieved the same using V3 endpoint, then it worked as expected.

**Response**

```
<Customer status="Synchronized">
    <Id>QB:190</Id>
    <SyncToken>1</SyncToken>
    <MetaData>
        <CreateTime>2014-03-20T03:41:51Z</CreateTime>
        <LastUpdatedTime>2014-03-20T03:44:07Z</LastUpdatedTime>
    </MetaData>
    <Organization>false</Organization>
    <DisplayName>TEL_CUST</DisplayName>
    <Active>true</Active>
    <PrimaryPhone>
        <FreeFormNumber>(555) 555-6286 x112</FreeFormNumber>
    </PrimaryPhone>
    <DefaultTaxCodeRef name="Tax">QB:1</DefaultTaxCodeRef>
    <ContactName>(555) 555-6286 x112</ContactName>
    <Job>false</Job>
    <TaxRateRef name="STax">QB:5</TaxRateRef>
    <Balance>0</Balance>
    <JobInfo>
        <Status>None</Status>
    </JobInfo>
</Customer>
```

**for Input** - [(555) 555-6286 x112]

```
<Customer status="Synchronized">
    <Id>QB:191</Id>
    <SyncToken>1</SyncToken>
    <MetaData>
        <CreateTime>2014-03-20T03:56:13Z</CreateTime>
        <LastUpdatedTime>2014-03-20T03:56:56Z</LastUpdatedTime>
    </MetaData>
    <Organization>false</Organization>
    <DisplayName>TEL_CUST1</DisplayName>
    <Active>true</Active>
    <PrimaryPhone>
        <FreeFormNumber>[(555) 555-6286 x112]</FreeFormNumber>
    </PrimaryPhone>
    <Fax>
        <FreeFormNumber>[(555) 555-6286 x112]</FreeFormNumber>
    </Fax>
    <DefaultTaxCodeRef name="Tax">QB:1</DefaultTaxCodeRef>
    <ContactName>[(555) 555-6286 x112]</ContactName>
    <Job>false</Job>
    <TaxRateRef name="STax">QB:5</TaxRateRef>
    <Balance>0</Balance>
    <JobInfo>
        <Status>None</Status>
    </JobInfo>
</Customer>
```

We'll raise a support ticket for this. I'll update this post if I come to know about its fix date.

Thanks